# How to run a "Desktop Entry" from another "Desktop Entry"?

Tags: desktop, freedesktop

Is somehow possible to run a "Desktop Entry" from another "Desktop Entry"?

Searching inside the [freedesktop Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) the answer seems "No".

What I want to do is to create a single "Desktop Entry" name "WorkStack" so that when it's called, it opens all the Application stack I use to work.

I know I could just refer to the applications in the stack with the bash executable location, but I would like to refer to them with the "Desktop Entry"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [dex](https://github.com/jceb/dex). It is a Python program meant to "generate and execute DesktopEntry files of the Application type" (quoting its manual).

Just put in your custom desktop entry a key along the lines of:

```
Exec=dex /path/to/application1.desktop /path/to/application2.desktop ...
```

(You may then be required to run `update-desktop-database` from [desktop-file-utils](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/desktop-file-utils/), or some equivalent utility provided by your desktop environment, to have your custom desktop entry show up in menus and other places).

Note that, as far as I can tell, while your desktop environment's application launcher may allow you to open a file or URL by typing `application-name /path/to/file`, `dex` doesn't allow for arguments to be passed to desktop entries from the command line.

As an alternative to `dex`, you may be able to use some command line utility provided by your desktop environment (e.g. `gtk-launch`) as discussed, for instance, in [this answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457422/315749) and some of the [answers to this question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/5172/882661).